# Changing frame colour based on a condition check

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am writing a tcl script to change the frame color based on license availability. If license is available it will show blue color else red color. This runs periodically(and frame color will be changed based on availability) using tcl every proc.

But when i tried pack forget to redraw the frame, In consecutive loop it says widget already exists. I am not able to use configure command for frame color as its not supported. 
Please suggest a solution.

```
#!/tools/tcl/tcl8.6/bin/tclsh -f

package require Tk

proc checkLic {} {
    set val [exec lmstat -a -c /tools/license/dat/cadence_orbit_3x.dat -f Liberate_MX_Client | grep issued | awk {{print $11}}]
    puts $val
    if {$val == 0} {
        after 1000
        pack forget .high
        after 1000
        frame  .high -width 8 -height 30 -background blue
        pack .high -side right
    } else {
        after 1000
        pack forget .high
        after 1000
        frame .high -width 8 -height 30 -background red
        pack .high -side right
    }
}

proc every {ms body} {
    eval $body
    after $ms [info level 0]
}

every 1000 {checkLic}
```

Comment: pack forget doesn't destroy the widget, it just removes it from the window. You can forget and re-manage the same widget multiple times.

Comment: Why are you putting a straight `after 1000` inside a callback?

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully address your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I didn’t think my answer through, sorry. I concentrated on the ways to display the background without noticing that you already had that covered. This code shows how you can get an oscillating display without the updating problems you mention. Basically the code creates the frame once and then just changes the color instead of un-managing it and trying to recreate it.

```
set gval 0

frame  .high -width 8 -height 30 -background blue
pack .high -side right

proc checkLic {} {
    # replace this with your own lookup code
    set val [set ::gval [expr {!$::gval}]]

    puts $val
    if {$val == 0} {
        .high configure -background blue
    } else {
        .high configure -background red
    }
}

proc every {ms body} {
    eval $body
    after $ms [info level 0]
}

every 1000 {checkLic}
```

**Old answer:**

A basic `frame` doesn't request any window area from its parent, so its background won't be visible.

To make the background visible you can set the height and width explicitly:

```
frame .high -height 20 -width 20 -background blue
pack .high
```

This should be visible as a blue square.

Another way to make the frame request window area is to give it content, but the background still won't be visible unless you specify a border width:

```
frame .high -borderwidth 10 -background blue
pack .high
label .high.txt -text foobar
pack .high.txt
```

In either case you can change the background color like this:

```
.high configure -background red
```

It could be that you would be better off using a `label` instead of a `frame`:

```
label .high -width 5 -background blue
pack .high
.high configure -background red
```

With a `label` you can switch between icons instead of changing the background color.

Documentation: [after](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/after.htm), [eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [frame](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/frame.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm), [label](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/label.htm), [pack](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)